# Как переделать запрос в laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Задача (бронирование):

есть поля data, date_from, date_to

необходимо в запрос передать дату '2022.09.15' и вывести все записи, где date <= '2022.09.15' и '2022.09.15' не находится в промежутке между date_from и date_to

Есть такой запрос, который нормально отрабатывает:

```
select
    *
from
    positions p
    left join reserved_positions rp on p.id = rp.position_id
where
    p.date <= '2022.09.15'
    and '2022.09.15' not between rp.date_from and rp.date_to
```

Как его правильно переделать в laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вроде здесь всё просто. Но для начала организовываете связи многие ко многим через модели. И после делаете следующее:

```
Position::where('date', '>=', '2022.09.15')
    ->whereHas('reserves', function($q) {
        $q->where('reserved_positions.date_from', '<=', '2022.09.15');
        $q->where('reserved_positions.date_to', '>=', '2022.09.15');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, вот так попробовать...

```php
Position::where('date', '>=', '2022.09.15')
    ->leftJoin('reserved_positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'reserved_positions.position_id')
    ->where('positions.date', '<=', '2022.09.15')
    ->whereBetween('2022.09.15', ['reserved_positions.date_from', 'reserved_positions.date_to'])
    ->get();
```